# Grouping SQL results by month

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server, group-by

I am trying to write a function that reads from an mssql database. Calculates the average number of days taken by engineering on a project and the percentage of on time projects and stores the results in my own Mongo database. Below is what I have, which works

```
async function update(m, y) {
  var query = "SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(day, DateBlockReleased, DateEngineeringTargetComplete)) AS AvgDays, SUM(IIF(DATEDIFF(day, DateBlockReleased, DateEngineeringTargetComplete)>=0, 1, 0)) AS OnTime, COUNT(DateBlockReleased) AS Total FROM JobData.JobData, JobData.BOMInfo, JobData.DesignInfo WHERE JobData.JobData.BOMInfoID = JobData.BOMInfo.BOMInfoID AND JobData.JobData.DesignInfoID = JobData.DesignInfo.DesignInfoID AND JobData.DesignInfo.DateEngineeringTargetComplete IS NOT NULL AND JobData.JobData.isArchivedDate IS NOT NULL AND MONTH(JobData.JobData.isArchivedDate) =" + m + " AND YEAR(JobData.JobData.isArchivedDate) =" + y;

  sql.connect(config, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error while connecting to database :- " + err);
    } else {
      var request = new sql.Request();
      request.query(query, function (err, rs) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error while querying database :- " + err);
          sql.close();
        } else {
          var record = {
            _id: m + "_" + y,
            AvgDays: rs.recordset[0].AvgDays,
            OnTime: rs.recordset[0].OnTime / rs.recordset[0].Total * 100
          };
          kpiConn.collection('engineeringData').insertOne(record);
          sql.close();
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

However when I run this for multiple months and years I get the records for the first 10 months and then abort errors from the SQL server. I believe this is because I am querying the database too many times at once and so I am trying to condense this into one SQL query but am struggling to group the results by month. I don't know whether it's easier to return the entire database with ontime calculated and then use javascript to group them? Also open to any suggestions to make my query in general more streamlined as I'm quite new to SQL (Have a feeling I should be using joins)

Comment: Have you tried a select all from database, then loop through the results after you have received them all, this should reduce the amount of effort on database.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a select all with a sort.

If you have a column in your database with months etc  and then also time taken you can run something like this.

```
SELECT column-list 
FROM table_name 
[WHERE condition] 
[ORDER BY column1, column2, .. columnN] [ASC | DESC];
```

For you would just be ;

```
select * FROM table_name
```

Hope this helps :)